# NSUserDefaults returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

Im trying to save an object to `NSUserdefaults` and then extract the same object.

```
//        let raw: AnyObject! = defaults.valueForKey("testKey")
//        let data = raw as NSData
//        
//        self.Report = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as DayReport
//        
//        println(Report.Day)


    Report.Day = "Mon"

    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.Report)

    println(data)

    defaults.setObject(data, forKey: "testKey")
    defaults.synchronize()
```

In this piece of code I save the object Report into `NSUserDefaults` encoded to `NSData`. `DayReport` is the type of `Report`

But when I switch the comment sections so the upper part of the code is not commented and the lower part is, the `let var = (nil)` and the program crashes. **Why?**

`DayReport` has the `NSCoding` protocol.

### Update

I added this:

```
    defaults.setObject(data, forKey: "testKey")
    defaults.synchronize()

    println(defaults.objectForKey("testKey"))
```

And it prints out nil, so it isnt getting saved properly but the data is not nil.

Comment: Can you show us the line of code where you set the "defaults" variable?

Comment: let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

Comment: just an idea, replace every `"testKey"` with `"testKey" as NSString` and check it out. Does it work?

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using `.valueForKey("testKey")` because this is using KVC to try to get a key that doesn't exist.

Instead you should be using `.objectForKey("testKey")`.

Comment: objectForKey() gives the exact same result, ive already tried both.

Comment: You get the same crash? Give the exception message and stack trace. Debug and log the entire contents of user defaults - what does it contain for that key?

Comment: Ive checked some more now and it isnt even getting saved

Comment: The encoded NSData of the object is not nil but when I save it it defaults returns nil.

Comment: How big is the data? Are you running on a device? How much disk space does it have free? Can you save a short string to defaults instead? You'll need to do some debugging around this issue...

Comment: I printed out data.lenght and it returned around 350, yes its on the simulator.

Comment: I got it to work... it was some mistakes in another area, but thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for set value to NSuserDefaults...

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1  forKey:@"your key"];//Remember your key to get data from NSuserDefaults
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

code for get value from NSuserDefaults...

```
  int CheckTimer = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"your key"];
```

I hope this help you....